# If raycast is not hitting an object - change the material color to white

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am working on a small school project in Unity for my IT classes.
I've created a script in Unityscript that shows specific GUI when the raycast hits and object with certain tag. I also want it to change the material color to yellow as soon as the raycast hits the object collider. This is the part I've managed to do.
Now I want my script to change the color back to white when the raycast stopped hitting the object colider but I can't think of any way to do this.

Could anyone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Here's my code - I know it's messy but it's my first time coding anything that's more complex.

Ah, since I was only testing it the material change is only on the "Wood" tag.

**Working code thanks to Romain Soual:**

```
#pragma strict

var rayLength : int = 2;

private var inventory : Inventory;

private var showGUI : boolean = false;

var bush : GameObject;
var player : GameObject;

var objHit : GameObject;

function Start()
{
    inventory = GameObject.Find("First Person Controller").GetComponent(Inventory);
}

function Update()
{
    var hit : RaycastHit;

    var forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, forward, hit, rayLength))
    {
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Wood")
        {   
            objHit = hit.collider.gameObject;       
            showGUI = true;
            objHit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.yellow;

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                inventory.wood++;
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                showGUI = false;
            }
        }
        else if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Sticks")
        {
            showGUI = true;

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                inventory.stick++;
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                showGUI = false;
            }
        }
        else if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "BushFull")
        {
            showGUI = true;
            bush = (hit.collider.gameObject);

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                inventory.berry += 5;
                bush.GetComponent(BushController).berriesTaken = true;
                showGUI = false;
            }
        }
        else if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Stones")
        {
            showGUI = true;

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                inventory.stone++;
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                showGUI = false;
            }
        }
        else if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Pickaxe")
        {
            showGUI = true;

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                inventory.pickaxe++;
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                showGUI = false;
            }
        }
        else if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Axe")
        {
            showGUI = true;

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                inventory.axe++;
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                showGUI = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            objHit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.white;
            showGUI = false;            
        }
    }
    else
    {
        objHit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.white;
        showGUI = false;        //jesli gracz oddali sie od obiektu to okienko "pick up" znika
    }
}

function OnGUI()
{
    if(showGUI == true)
    {
        GUI.Box(Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 100, 25), "Pick up ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Update function, you can save the current object being colored in yellow in a variable highlightedGameObject and compare it to the last highlighted Game Object. If they differ, make the last one go white ; end the function by saving highlightedGameObject in a variable lastHighlightedGameObject.

```
var highlightedGameObject;
var lastHighlightedGameObject;

function Update () {
[...]
highlightedGameObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
highlightedGameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.yellow;
[...]
if (highlightedGameObject != lastHighlightedGameObject && lastHighlightedGameObject != null) {
    lastHighlightedGameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.white;
}
lastHighlightedGameObject = highlightedGameObject;
}
```

I hope that helps =)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After few tries I managed to get it working :)

Comment: The only problem now is that when I don't have selected object yet it's spamming errors that objHit is not assigned. Same when I destroy the object. Do you know any way do fix it?

Comment: Nice work ;)
I edited my answer to show the code I described, just in case somebody else looked.

If you have errors showing, just add **if (objHit != null)** before putting the last highlighted Game Object to white, it should do the trick.